# I sent the BTC to a wrong address

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, address

I was trying to transact BTC and the end receiver gave me an address. I couldn't afford the amount due to spreads on transactions so we lowered the amount, made a new address and i sent it but I accidentally sent it to the first address and not the second. What can I do? The BTC already left my account and I'm sure it won't reach theirs because the transaction was declined.

Comment: What kind of wallet did you send it from? And what do you mean it was declined? What is the address you sent it too and can the receiver not access the BTC at the original address?

Comment: I sent it from my exodus wallet. I'm not sure how to get the money back, the address was cancelled before I sent my BTC then I sent my BTC to that address. It has been confirmed  6 times already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect bitcoin address funded](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45729/incorrect-bitcoin-address-funded)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is ask the owner of the address you sent the bitcoin to to send the bitcoin back to you. There is no such thing as a "declined" transaction in bitcoin; transactions that get included in a block are final.

Comment: They sent me an address to send the BTC to. But the amount was too much, I couldn't cover fees so I cancelled the transaction. I then restarted again and they sent another address. I input the coin amount but I forgot to change the address. It sent the BTC to the first address and I don't know what happens to it on their end. I just got confirmation that my transaction was cancelled but my BTC hasn't been returned. I dont' know what to do.

Comment: @JonathanBenjamin Do you know who owns "the first address"? Ask its owner to refund you.